# can C# application be downloaded to web browser and run purely on the user's computer?

Tags: c#

I want to make a C# application that accepts an XLS data file from from a users via web browser, perform calculations on the data, and then returns a new XLS data file to the user.  Traditionally, I would make an MVC.net app, have a user upload data via web browser, the app would do processing on the web server, and then return an XLS for the user to download. The processing of the data is like a blackbox...there is no interaction needed form the user.  Just upload, wait a few seconds, and get results to download.

With Blazor, and maybe other tech developments, is there a way for my DLLs and the entire C# application to be executed inside the user's web browser on their computer.  This would remove the network bandwidth of transfering data up, and then downloading the results.

However, I do not want an Exe to be installed on the client's machine.  I want the app to reside on the web server, and only be temporarily downloaded to the user's browser at run-time, then be deleted.  Sort of like how a Javascript SPA application might run.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Look up "ClickOnce".

Comment: Is your requirement that the app/code stays on the server and you communicate with it only via the browser/web page or do you want to download and execute the code? Keep in mind that you can download any ".exe" file and execute it, you don't need to "install" the application.

Comment: Blazor is exactly what you asked for, and you just need to spend more time on it, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0